# image without source link in html

Tags: css, html, dom

Interestingly I came across a web page where it has image ,but when I am able to see the source code I cant see its source, I mean the link to the actual image. since I am developing a webpage (beginner), I would like to know how to achieve. I am not sure whether its an image, or it is coming through CSS.

[image]

and the site below

https://www.debuggex.com/pricing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an image but a character specified using CSS:

```
content: "\f023";
```

This is achieved using [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/). You can apply classes to elements (in this case, `icon-lock`) and the styles are automatically applied using this third party open source thingy.

Comment: or in "background-image" this <img/>

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński No.

Comment: bootstrap plugins are changing my knowledge of web development completely!! thanks for the Q and answer.

Comment: @GrantThomas as per your answer, i dont want to add any external resource in my page to achieve this right? just adding content will do this !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Because this is iconic font design it does not have image

If you like to include your project add css

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then use class like this

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> Library</a></li>
```

Refer

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Answer (score 0):

In this example it is not an image. The padlock is a font and circle around a style (CSS).

```
<span class="callout-pic"> <!-- Circle -->
    <i class="icon-lock"></i> <!-- Padlock icon -->
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

generating image using the base64 encoding,

```
background: url(data:image/png;base64,.....)
```

Ref: http://base64img.com/#encode

Answer (score 0):

@GrantThomas is right, Content use in css but basic use call to systems Symbol example Copyright Symbol, Percent Symbol, Left Right Arrow and more work etc. If you want to use this then you do not need any external resource in your page. Simply in your page call font which available in your system and right some code and if you want to some specific symbol then download font.

Example downloaded font :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<title>DingbatsOne Regular Specimen</title>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'dingbatsoneregular';
src: url('dingbat1-webfont.eot');
src: url('dingbat1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('dingbat1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('dingbat1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('dingbat1-webfont.svg#dingbatsoneregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
#target {font-family: 'dingbatsoneregular';}
#target:before {content: "A"; font-size: 200px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in CSS and beginner but may be this is helpful to you.